# Heroku Redis Keyspace Notifications?

Tags: heroku, redis

Does heroku redis have the ability to enable keyspace notifications?

Indeed, is it possible to alter any CONFIG vars beyond maxmemory-policy and timeout?

I have trawled through the docs and cant find any and am unable to alter the config from my app or by logging in remote, recieving the following error:

```
ERR unknown command 'config' heroku
```

-- Edit for others who may have a similar issue, ive since migrated to Redis Cloud which allows config changes including the one I was after, setting keyspace notifications for expiry events.